# two references in STDIN with pipe

Tags: stack, pipe, stdin, exploit

I'm trying to exploit a .c, and it asks for 2 inputs. I have to use hexadecimal entries to change the return adress to whatever I want. How can I pipe an input for two entries at the same time? Is that possible?

Comment: What? Your question couldn't be less clear. Please post the .c code and more details on what you're trying to do and why.